# How to translate INSERT INTO ... SELECT to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know what's the equivalent of this MySQL command in MongoDB.

```
INSERT INTO xyz (field1, field2, field3, field4)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, NOW() FROM t1, t2, t3
```

I've been using MongoDB for only 48 hours and I'm afraid I just can't figure that one out.

Thanks for everything :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't do joins so your first three steps are:

1. Grab `t1.id` from MongoDB and put it in `t1_id`.
2. Grab `t2.id` from MongoDB and put it in `t2_id`.
3. Grab `t3.id` from MongoDB and put it in `t3_id`.

Then, you can use [`new Timestamp()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Timestamp+Data+Type) in place of `NOW()`:

```
db.xyz.insert({
    field1: t1_id,
    field2: t2_id,
    field3: t3_id,
    field4: new Timestamp()
});
```

If you're really doing a three way cross product, then you'll have to wrap the above in a triple nested loop something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < all_t1_ids.length; ++i) {
    for(var j = 0; j < all_t2_ids.length; ++j) {
        for(var k = 0; k < all_t3_ids.length; ++k) {
            db.xyz.insert({
                field1: all_t1_ids[i],
                field2: all_t2_ids[j],
                field3: all_t3_ids[k],
                field4: new Timestamp()
            });
         }
     }
}
```

You have to do a lot of traditional RDBMS things by hand with MongoDB.

Comment: But if my original MySQL query inserted around 400K records, will the one you suggested do the same? From the look of it, it looks like it will only insert one.

Comment: @Pierre: You'd have to wrap it in a loop, I'll add a little update to that effect.